# How recreate navigation animations

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the navigation bar from this [website](https://webflow.com) and can't work out how to do the following two things:

1. Create the page background overlay on hover of the submenu
2. How to make the submenu have the same expand reveal on hover of the link.

```css
body {
  font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .25px;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ededed;
}


.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 40;
}

.nav li {
  color: #000;
}

.nav li a {
  cursor: pointer
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: fit-content;
}

.nav ul:hover li {
  color: #eee;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
  color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 35px 20px 0;
}

.three:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 200px;
}

.sub-menu {
  height: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.col-1-4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.service {
  padding: 20%;
}

.nav.servicesIsHovered {
  background-color: #272727;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="one">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="two">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="three">
        <a class="">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="four">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I previously tried getting the overlay to work by adding a separate div to the end of the code and setting the opacity to zero, I then added more code to change the opacity to one, however, this failed.

What would be the best practise to achieve the two aspects above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-menu is done using absolute positioning and making all the ancestors up until the container not have any positioning (or default static positioning), so the sub-menu is positioned absolutely to the container.

The expand reveal is done using a height animation - the sub-menu has a fixed height that is animated on hover of the parent li

The overlay is done using fixed positioning and javascript - whenever you see inline styles change like that, you know it's js animation and not css.

Below I have added jQuery and shown a quick demo of how they may have done it

```js
var $overlay = $('.overlay');
$('.sub-menu').parent()
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
      $overlay.fadeIn('fast');
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      $overlay.fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .25px;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ededed;
}

.header {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background:blue; /* needs a colour so you cannot see overlay behind */
}

.nav {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 40;
}

.nav li {
  color: #000;
}

.nav li a {
  cursor: pointer
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: fit-content;
}

.nav ul:hover li {
  color: #eee;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
  color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 35px 20px 0;
}

li:hover>.sub-menu {
  height: 200px;
}

.sub-menu {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* hide the overflow so you don't need to worry about display and opacity */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: height 1s ease;
  /* add this for your animation and remove display none */
}

.col-1-4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.service {
  padding: 20%;
}

.nav.servicesIsHovered {
  background-color: #272727;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
  display:none;
  /* above the body but below the header */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="one">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="two">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="three">
        <a class="">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="four">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Absolute legend! Thanks for helping me out with this.

Comment: No worries, you were almost there, just think you got a little stuck with the animation.  Have added a couple of comments that should explain what's happening

Comment: I can't work out the overlay. Do you mind adding it to the code for me?

Comment: Ok they actually use js for the overlay - whenever you see inline styles changing - that's js and not css

Comment: The page background overlay where the opacity is set to 0.5, for example, to darken the page out.

Comment: See edit to answer - you need to use a bit of javascript to do it